# Possible to get the email content from MFMailComposeViewController?

Tags: ios, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

Is it possible to retrieve the email content (To, From, Subject, Body, ...) from the MFMailComposeViewController after the user click the "Send" button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You can't get any details about what the user enters into any field.